# display wp_postmeta meta_value in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

please help a new member

THE ISSUE:
I have a POS on my WC and it doesn't display sequential orders numbering, so I am using other plugin to achieve this. I need to display the value of a *meta_value* from my database in the order receipt (printable ticket) after the order is placed. So, the *meta_value* I need to display on the POS's tickets is the sequential ticket number created by the other plugin.

Gladly this other plugin creates the sequential number in the database from where I hope I can retrieve it somehow. 
This *meta_value* for example "T00001...T00009"  has the *meta_key* = *"_order_number"* and it's within *wp5o_postmeta* table of my sql database.

I believe it must be easy for you guys...

Thank you so much
[Image of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgTSi.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this filter and implement your post meta

wordpress/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-openpos/includes/front/Front.php

line 4683

$result['data'] = apply_filters('op_get_next_order_number_info',$order_number_info);